# JavaScript if condition not working

Tags: javascript

I am screwed with this one the if statement is not working in javascript.
I am using js to call php and php file echo 'true';

My java script code

```
 function like_add(article_id){
$.post('my/like.php', {article_id:article_id}, function(data){
    if(data == 'true'){//this part never works
        alert(data);
    }else{
    alert(data);
    }
});
```

}

I tried to change alert with `alert('*'+data+'*');`

And got that there is a space * true*.
How can I get this script t work.

Whole code

```
 function like_add(article_id){
$.post('ajax/like.php', {article_id:article_id}, function(data){

    if(data == 'true'){
        total_votes(article_id);
    }else{
    alert(data);
    }
});
```

}
PHP code

```
        if(previously_liked($article_id) === true){
        echo 'You\'ve already liked this!';                 
        }else{
            add_like($article_id);
            echo 'true';
        }


function total_votes(article_id){
$.post('ajax/total_votes.php', {article_id:article_id}, function(data){
    $('#article_'+article_id).text(data);
```

});
}

Comment: Wait ... if the PHP code echoes "success", where does the string with "true" in it come from?

Comment: Please post your actual code. I've a strong feeling that this is an untested reduced example. And define "not working". Are you saying that neither condition executes? Or is it always the `else`?

Comment: @am not i am the if is not working as there is white space before string which is echoed an I have tried all sort of methods but nothing worked!! else is working fine

Comment: @NavneetPandey: What happens if you do `alert(typeof data)` *before* the `if` statement.

Comment: You're saying that `alert(typeof data);` doesn't show? That's hard to believe if your other alerts were working.

Comment: there was some error it alerts the data twice

Comment: @NavneetPandey: Using `typeof` alerts the data? It should give you the type.

Comment: it gives me string as an alert

Comment: And you're saying that you *always* get the `else`, or is it that sometimes nothing happens?

Comment: @NavneetPandey: And what happens if you do `alert(data.length);`. Something is wrong here. Pointy's second solution should work.

Comment: using alert(data.length) i am getting 6 but the true is 4 and one space that makes it to 5

Comment: And what about `alert($.trim(data).length);`

Comment: @NavneetPandey: Then try `if($.trim(data) == 'true') {`

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: @NavneetPandey: So it goes to the `else`? or nothing happens?

Comment: yeah every time it goes to else

Comment: @NavneetPandey: Before the `if`, do this `$.map($.trim(data), alert)` Do you get each lowercase character in the string?

Comment: yes I am getting each character as lower case

Comment: Then try this `if($.trim(data) == 'true') { alert('It works');`, so that `alert('It works');` goes before `total_votes(article_id)`

Comment: @NavneetPandey: So then the issue is not with the `if` not working, but rather the issue is with your `total_votes()` function not behaving as expected.

Comment: but if the if condition is made true some how like if(1 == 1) it works

Comment: @NavneetPandey: Have you posted your actual code, or did you modify it before posting?

Comment: its actual code now actual code

Comment: Is it the `alert()` inside the `if` that makes it work? Does it work if you put an `alert('foo');` inside the `total_votes()` function, *before* the `$.post`? Also, does this run when the page loads?

Comment: got it to work there was one more problem $.trim works fine and the script works nicely Thanks for your help thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Well you could include a space in your test:

```
  if (data == ' true') { ... }
```

Or you could look for the pattern "true" in the data:

```
  if (/true/.test(data)) { ... }
```

The latter would probably be more resilient, though really it'd be better to have your server return something more structured and less ambiguous.

Comment: Well you're going to have to provide more detail; the regular expression would definitely work.

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` *before* the `if`, just to be sure that `data` is what you expect it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do following:

1. Check your response that should not contains space.
   Or
2. Use `data = data.replace(/\s/g, "");`

Comment: I have tried this. in this also if condition is not working but the alert is without space.

Comment: can you try like  if(data == true), I mean without single or double qoutes.

Comment: I think your callback function is returning ' true' (true with space). If it return 'true' (without space) then it will work. Hope this help.

Comment: Use data = data.replace(/\s/g, ""); before if condition.

Comment: Debug it in firefox with firebug, if you know how to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a leading space bugging you, try

```
if (data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').toLowerCase() === 'true')
```